# Javascript strip decimal from numeric

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, decimal, strip

I'm using Math.random to generate a random string passed in an ajax call.   The problem is that the string generated contains a decimal, and the server interprets this as a file.ext (which of course doesn't exist).

Ex from http.log:

```
File does not exist: /path/to/site/foo.php&arg=123&randval=0.5678719817071954, referer: http://site/bar.php?arg=123
```

Ajax used to generate link:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(\"#placeholder\").load(\"/foo.php?arg=123\");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() 
    {
        $(\"#placeholder\").load('/foo.php?arg=123&randval='+ Math.random());
    }, 5000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

What I'd like to end up with is:

```
foo.php&arg=123&randval=05678719817071954
```

The argument `randval` is not used other than to ensure I don't wind up with a cached version of the page.  It may not be needed, but this is from an example I used to set up the jquery ajax call.

Comment: Error: TypeError: Math.random().replace is not a function  (EDIT, previous commenter deleted this suggestion)

Comment: replace only works with strings, not numbers, use toString() or see the answer by David below.

Comment: @acoder: yeah, I know (I figured that out about five seconds after I posted the comment, with a fairly major "d'oh!" moment...).

Comment: We both had a major "d'oh!" moment -- the link I was writing used an ampersand instead of question mark for the first argument.  Fixing that solved the problem of 'file not found'.   Thanks again for the answers- useful to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, in place of `Math.random()`, using:

```
(Math.random() + '').replace('.','');
```

Comment: Ok this works -- some others suggest using Date instead of Math.  Is there a performance benefit?

Comment: @acoder no. The only downside to `+new Date` is if you fire two requests in rapid succession you might get the same value for both.

Comment: Not really (so far as I've experienced), it's a different means to achieve the same result. it's worth bearing in mind that `Math.random()` can result in the same number twice (random guarantees nothing, after all); whereas `Date().getTime()` isn't going to return the same time twice (assuming a delay between calls to the `getTime()` method).

Comment: @DavidThomas in fact it's the opposite. Date().getTime() *will* return the same value if called in the same loop, while you have a one in a million chance of getting a duplicate random number.

Comment: @RicardoTomasi: but is that because of the speed of a JavaScript loop, or due to some other factor? (Note that I did, albeit in a quick edit, take notice of the requirement of a delay between calls to the function...)

Comment: @DavidThomas the minimum date increment is `1ms`, you can run a lot of code in that time. If you need really unique ids, use a UUID generator (https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid). Math.random() is not that random :)

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` returns a value between `0` and `1`, to get numbers between `0` and `max` you need to multiply it by `max`. This should do:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e16) // 1e16 == 10000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe easier and more common ... if you don't need to use Math.random()

```
 + (new Date()).getTime();
```

Comment: just `+new Date` gets you the same value.

Answer (score 0):

why not use `new Date().getTime()` and avoid all the hassle

Comment: Is there a performance benefit in using Date vs Math?  Otherwise it won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are right on - but I overlooked an obvious type-o in my code.  The link I was writing:

```
foo.php&arg=123
```

Should be

foo.php?arg=123

```
enter code here
```

Once I updated, the file not found error was resolved.

Thanks for the suggestions on fixing the Math/decimal issue - not needed now, but useful to know.